# What are the arguments to `new` from a contract object?

Tags: go-ethereum

In the greeter tutorial, the greeterContract is deployed using `new`:

```
var greeterContract = web3.eth.contract(greeterCompiled.greeter.info.abiDefinition);
var greeter = greeterContract.new(_greeting,{from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: greeterCompiled.greeter.code, gas: 10000000000000}, function(e, contract){...
```

What exactly are the arguments I'm providing to the function?

Where in the go-ethereum source code is the `new` function defined?

Where in the go-ethereum source code is the `web3` class defined?

Answer (score 3):

The "new" is a nice form to write a sendTransaction.

The web3 interface transform your params using the contract abi to write the sendTransaction command.

```
contract.new(param_1, param_2, ..., param_n , options, callback)
```

The first parameters (param_1, .. , param_n) will be passed to your contract constructor.

Only the last two parameters can have extra meaning. See the implementation of [function new](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/master/lib/web3/contract.js#L179) to check how they check for these parameters.

Comment: In the greeter tutorial, the callback function is entered line by line on the geth console which i find rather cumbersome. Can I define the callback in a js script and load the function using loadScript and then supply the reference to that function as callback?

Comment: @TMOTTM Sorry, but I don't know. Generally I don't use the geth console for complex things like async transactions.