# Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount

Tags: web3js, gas, contract-deployment

I am using the below code to create the contact it give the error:

```
Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.
```

Code:

```
primaryAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];

//Multisignature source code
var testSource=' contract multiowned { struct PendingState { uint yetNeeded; uint ownersDone; uint index; } event Confirmation(address owner, bytes32 operation); event Revoke(address owner, bytes32 operation); event OwnerChanged(address oldOwner, address newOwner); event OwnerAdded(address newOwner); event OwnerRemoved(address oldOwner); event RequirementChanged(uint newRequirement); modifier onlyowner { if (isOwner(msg.sender)) _ } modifier onlymanyowners(bytes32 _operation) { if (confirmAndCheck(_operation)) _ } function multiowned(address[] _owners, uint _required) { m_numOwners = _owners.length + 1; m_owners[1] = uint(msg.sender); m_ownerIndex[uint(msg.sender)] = 1; for (uint i = 0; i < _owners.length; ++i) { m_owners[2 + i] = uint(_owners[i]); m_ownerIndex[uint(_owners[i])] = 2 + i; } m_required = _required; } function revoke(bytes32 _operation) external { uint ownerIndex = m_ownerIndex[uint(msg.sender)]; if (ownerIndex == 0) return; uint ownerIndexBit = 2**ownerIndex; var pending = m_pending[_operation]; if (pending.ownersDone & ownerIndexBit > 0) { pending.yetNeeded++; pending.ownersDone -= ownerIndexBit; Revoke(msg.sender, _operation); } } function changeOwner(address _from, address _to) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external { if (isOwner(_to)) return; uint ownerIndex = m_ownerIndex[uint(_from)]; if (ownerIndex == 0) return; clearPending(); m_owners[ownerIndex] = uint(_to); m_ownerIndex[uint(_from)] = 0; m_ownerIndex[uint(_to)] = ownerIndex; OwnerChanged(_from, _to); } function addOwner(address _owner) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external { if (isOwner(_owner)) return; clearPending(); if (m_numOwners >= c_maxOwners) reorganizeOwners(); if (m_numOwners >= c_maxOwners) return; m_numOwners++; m_owners[m_numOwners] = uint(_owner); m_ownerIndex[uint(_owner)] = m_numOwners; OwnerAdded(_owner); } function removeOwner(address _owner) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external { uint ownerIndex = m_ownerIndex[uint(_owner)]; if (ownerIndex == 0) return; if (m_required > m_numOwners - 1) return; m_owners[ownerIndex] = 0; m_ownerIndex[uint(_owner)] = 0; clearPending(); reorganizeOwners(); OwnerRemoved(_owner); } function changeRequirement(uint _newRequired) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external { if (_newRequired > m_numOwners) return; m_required = _newRequired; clearPending(); RequirementChanged(_newRequired); } function isOwner(address _addr) returns (bool) { return m_ownerIndex[uint(_addr)] > 0; } function hasConfirmed(bytes32 _operation, address _owner) constant returns (bool) { var pending = m_pending[_operation]; uint ownerIndex = m_ownerIndex[uint(_owner)]; if (ownerIndex == 0) return false; uint ownerIndexBit = 2**ownerIndex; if (pending.ownersDone & ownerIndexBit == 0) { return false; } else { return true; } } function confirmAndCheck(bytes32 _operation) internal returns (bool) { uint ownerIndex = m_ownerIndex[uint(msg.sender)]; if (ownerIndex == 0) return; var pending = m_pending[_operation]; if (pending.yetNeeded == 0) { pending.yetNeeded = m_required; pending.ownersDone = 0; pending.index = m_pendingIndex.length++; m_pendingIndex[pending.index] = _operation; } uint ownerIndexBit = 2**ownerIndex; if (pending.ownersDone & ownerIndexBit == 0) { Confirmation(msg.sender, _operation); if (pending.yetNeeded <= 1) { delete m_pendingIndex[m_pending[_operation].index]; delete m_pending[_operation]; return true; } else { pending.yetNeeded--; pending.ownersDone |= ownerIndexBit; } } } function reorganizeOwners() private returns (bool) { uint free = 1; while (free < m_numOwners) { while (free < m_numOwners && m_owners[free] != 0) free++; while (m_numOwners > 1 && m_owners[m_numOwners] == 0) m_numOwners--; if (free < m_numOwners && m_owners[m_numOwners] != 0 && m_owners[free] == 0) { m_owners[free] = m_owners[m_numOwners]; m_ownerIndex[m_owners[free]] = free; m_owners[m_numOwners] = 0; } } } function clearPending() internal { uint length = m_pendingIndex.length; for (uint i = 0; i < length; ++i) if (m_pendingIndex[i] != 0) delete m_pending[m_pendingIndex[i]]; delete m_pendingIndex; } uint public m_required; uint public m_numOwners; uint[256] m_owners; uint constant c_maxOwners = 250; mapping(uint => uint) m_ownerIndex; mapping(bytes32 => PendingState) m_pending; bytes32[] m_pendingIndex; } contract daylimit is multiowned { modifier limitedDaily(uint _value) { if (underLimit(_value)) _ } function daylimit(uint _limit) { m_dailyLimit = _limit; m_lastDay = today(); } function setDailyLimit(uint _newLimit) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external { m_dailyLimit = _newLimit; } function resetSpentToday() onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external { m_spentToday = 0; } function underLimit(uint _value) internal onlyowner returns (bool) { if (today() > m_lastDay) { m_spentToday = 0; m_lastDay = today(); } if (m_spentToday + _value >= m_spentToday && m_spentToday + _value <= m_dailyLimit) { m_spentToday += _value; return true; } return false; } function today() private constant returns (uint) { return now / 1 days; } uint public m_dailyLimit; uint public m_spentToday; uint public m_lastDay; } contract multisig { event Deposit(address from, uint value); event SingleTransact(address owner, uint value, address to, bytes data); event MultiTransact(address owner, bytes32 operation, uint value, address to, bytes data); event ConfirmationNeeded(bytes32 operation, address initiator, uint value, address to, bytes data); function changeOwner(address _from, address _to) external; function execute(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data) external returns (bytes32); function confirm(bytes32 _h) returns (bool); } contract Wallet is multisig, multiowned, daylimit { uint public version = 2; struct Transaction { address to; uint value; bytes data; } function Wallet(address[] _owners, uint _required, uint _daylimit) multiowned(_owners, _required) daylimit(_daylimit) { } function kill(address _to) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external { suicide(_to); } function() { if (msg.value > 0) Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value); } function execute(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data) external onlyowner returns (bytes32 _r) { if (underLimit(_value)) { SingleTransact(msg.sender, _value, _to, _data); _to.call.value(_value)(_data); return 0; } _r = sha3(msg.data, block.number); if (!confirm(_r) && m_txs[_r].to == 0) { m_txs[_r].to = _to; m_txs[_r].value = _value; m_txs[_r].data = _data; ConfirmationNeeded(_r, msg.sender, _value, _to, _data); } } function confirm(bytes32 _h) onlymanyowners(_h) returns (bool) { if (m_txs[_h].to != 0) { m_txs[_h].to.call.value(m_txs[_h].value)(m_txs[_h].data); MultiTransact(msg.sender, _h, m_txs[_h].value, m_txs[_h].to, m_txs[_h].data); delete m_txs[_h]; return true; } } function clearPending() internal { uint length = m_pendingIndex.length; for (uint i = 0; i < length; ++i) delete m_txs[m_pendingIndex[i]]; super.clearPending(); } mapping (bytes32 => Transaction) m_txs; }'

// Solidity process
var testCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(testSource);

//contract process
var testContract = web3.eth.contract(testCompiled.multisig.info.abiDefinition);

contractData = web3.eth.contract(testCompiled.multisig.info.abiDefinition).new.getData({data: testCompiled.multisig.code});
console.log("estimating gas price of creating B...");
var gasEstimate = web3.eth.estimateGas({data: contractData});
console.log(gasEstimate);

//deploying process
multisig = testContract.new({
    from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
    data: testCompiled.multisig.code, gas: gasEstimate+3000}, 
    function(e, contract) {

     if(!e) {

    if(!contract.address) {
      console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");

    } else {
      //Once get this message we can call the functions
      console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
      console.log(contract);
    }

  }
  else
  {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: In the `testContract.new`, instead of `gas: gasEstimate+3000` have you tried `gas: 3000000` ?

Comment: i checked with gas: 3000000 price same error occur then only i change the estimated gas now also got the same issue . If i give high amount then it says gas amount exceeds. i can't guess what is the problem

Comment: Can you please format your code to make it easier for other people to read and help? (Use the { } "Preformatted text" option.)

Comment: lesyk fixed it with solc, but did not use the estimateGas function. solc is definitely the way to go for compiling these days, and I added 50000 to the estimateGas result I got and it works! The only wonder is that the estimate errs on the low side instead of the high. What were they thinkin' ?

Answer (score 6):

This error occurs because geth doesn't always calculate the contract storage cost correctly. Try adding 20-50000 gas and see if that fixes the error.

Please feel free to submit an issue in the go ethereum repository.

Answer (score 4):

Have had same issue, fixed via using solc compilation:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const Web3 = require('web3');
const solc = require('solc')

let web3 = new Web3();

let account = web3.personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.accounts[0], 'password');
let source = fs.readFileSync('nameContract.sol', 'utf8');
let compiledContract = solc.compile(source, 1);
let abi = compiledContract.contracts['nameContract'].interface;
console.log('Abi: ', abi);
let bytecode = compiledContract.contracts['nameContract'].bytecode;
let gasEstimate = web3.eth.estimateGas({data: bytecode});
let contract = web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(abi));
contract.new({from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data:bytecode, value:30000000000000000000, gas:gasEstimate}, function(err, myContract){
  if(!err) {
     if(!myContract.address) {
         console.log("Hash: ", myContract.transactionHash);
     } else {
         console.log("Address: ", myContract.address);
     }
  }
  else {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can occur if you're using inheritance incorrectly in your contract. For instance,

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Base {
  uint foo;
  function Base(uint _foo) {
    foo = _foo;
  }
}

contract Derived is Base {
  function Derived() {}
}
```

Can you spot the error? [Inheritance](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#inheritance) is being done incorrectly here because you need to specify the arguments of the base contract's constructor in your derived contract:

```
contract Derived is Base(28) {
  function Derived() {}
}
```

or:

```
contract Derived is Base {
  function Derived(uint _bar) Base(_bar * 2) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the hard way one more reason why this happens: failing constructor calls.

My setup:

- Windows
- Truffle v4.1.8
- Geth 1.8.8-stable
- Running a light node with command `geth.exe -syncmode light --testnet --rpc --rpcapi eth,net,web3,personal`
- Attaching Geth with `geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8545` and unlocking account
- Running Truffle with `truffle.cmd test --network ropsten`

You will get the OP's error with (at least) this setup if you have a failing `require` somewhere in a constructor. For example:

```
contract A {
    constructor() public {
        require(false);
    }
}
```

So remember to also double-check your `require` calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you encauntering

`Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.`

While deploing into private network througth truffle suite, then it may be **wrong evm version on remote node**

Always check evm version and it differencing from production enviroment

Also you should check for which version of evm truffle use for compilation. It may be found at `truffle.js`