# Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount , when creating new contract

Tags: contract-development, web3js, parity

I am trying to create new contract but I get the error:

> Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas
>   amount.

In the script, I have:

```
var balance =  web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[1])
console.log(balance.toNumber());
console.log('balance: ' + web3.fromWei(balance));

var gasPrice = web3.eth.gasPrice;
console.log('gasPrice '+gasPrice.toString(10));

contractData = web3.eth.contract(abi).new.getData({data: compiled});

var gasEstimate = web3.eth.estimateGas({data: contractData});
console.log('gas Estimate '+gasEstimate);
var total = gasEstimate*gasPrice;

console.log('total: ' + web3.fromWei(total));

web3.eth.contract(abi).new({from:accounts[1],data: compiled,gas:gasEstimate+3000}, function (err, contract) { ....
```

The output is:

> balance: 15.95038514
>
> gasPrice 20000000000
>
> gas Estimate 84251
>
> total: 0.00168502

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Btw, I am running the **Parity** client.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the gas even more? I don't know about Parity, but in python I've had some trouble with gas estimation. An easy check is to set the gas to the gas limit.

Comment: @4gn3s yep I did. I tried 100k and even more. same thing. Only visible effect is when I try to put to little gas. then it try to put contract in the block but it fails and give up after 50 blocks. And btw it works with testrpc

Comment: Try this: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11142/5558

Answer (score 3):

Running Parity with

> --geth

flag fixed the issue.

More [here](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/issues/2434)

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: Yeah if anyone could provide an explanation for why the --geth flag is necessary, that would be cool