# Solve Git Code Error Contract Crowdsale

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, testrpc

I am getting the following error when doing truffle migrate on the following code: https://github.com/CoinFabrik/ico/tree/9ac3487b6103c96958cdabf8b9ce2071a7250cd8

```
Deploying Crowdsale...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.
```

I changed the truffle.js to reflect the first testrpc account 
I am deploying on testrpc (testrpc -p portnumber )

Could someone please help me in what I am doing wrong?

What  I have tried so far amongst others:

[Truffle v3.2.5 migration error: contract code couldn't be stored](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18690/truffle-v3-2-5-migration-error-contract-code-couldnt-be-stored)

[Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount , when creating new contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8973/error-the-contract-code-couldnt-be-stored-please-check-your-gas-amount-when)

1. I have increased the gas in the truffle.js file
2. Someone said my account needs to be unlocked but I am on testrpc
3. I also saw somewhere that I need to use `payable` on the constructor
       but I am not sure where.
4. Use --network testrpc
5. Found out that the problem is with this line:
   `await deployer.deploy(Crowdsale, MultiSigWallet.address, config.tests.startBlock, config.tests.endBlock, accounts[0], {gas:
   4200000});`

Comment: If you're specifying a non-standard port for testrpc, have you told Truffle what it is?

Comment: Yes, actually I specified the same port of 20487 found in https://github.com/CoinFabrik/ico/blob/9ac3487b6103c96958cdabf8b9ce2071a7250cd8/truffle.js