# Contract deployment without solidity online compiler

Tags: contract-development, javascript, meteor

I am new to the dApp development. I want to deploy a contract to Ethereum through a website i am building. However i don't want the user to do it through the solidity online compiler or mist wallet. I want the user to press a button and the contract to automatically deploy on the Ethereum (backend function). I am using meteor for this project. Any suggestions on how to implement something like that?
Thank you

Comment: Have you had a look at deployment from NodeJs? http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7255/deploy-contract-from-nodejs

Comment: Yes I have. Let me show you an example of what i am trying to do.

`var source = "" + 
   "contract demo {\n" +
    "   string public name = 'Petros';\n" +
    "   function changeName(string _newName){\n" +
    "     name = _newName;\n" +
    "   }\n" +
    "}\n";
    
var compiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(source,
    function(err,res){      //necessary callback function
      console.log(compiled);
});
console.log(compiled); 
`
However the code doesn't appear to compile and nothing shows in the console

Comment: Make your Solidity source code as a one line string. Plus, why do you `console.log(compiled)` if it is `res` that you get?

Comment: Yes i tried the source code in one line string. yea i should have written `console.log(res)` which does return an object with too many options that i don't understand. However there is still the problem that `console.log(compiled);`  in the end won't return anything. I can't find a way to interact to interact with the returned `res` object. i.e. how can i retrieve the string "petros" from the contract i deployed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you run this in Geth console?

```
> var source = "contract demo { string public name = 'Petros'; function changeName(string _newName){ name = _newName; }}";

> var compiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(source);

> web3.eth.compile.solidity(source, function(err, res) { console.log(JSON.stringify(res)); });
```

The ABI will be `compiled.demo.info.abiDefinition`.

If you make an asynchronous call in Javascript, then what you get is in the callback, it is not in the returned thingy.

So this does not work:

```
var thisWillBeUndefinedObviously = web3.eth.compile.solidity(source, function(err, res) { console.log(JSON.stringify(res)); });
```

Comment: Ok so my return would be console.log(JSON.stringify(res)) from the callback function got it. However it doesn't show anywhere the contract address or abi so i can retrieve my string later. 
Also i wasn't using geth. deployed a couple of contracts through mist and solidity-metamask. I downloaded it, first command you told me to run was undefined and the second is still syncing the blockchain

Comment: I edited my answer to tell you where is the ABI you missed. Compilation is one step. After, you need to deploy your contract, which gives you an address. The commands I gave you return undefined because they create variables. Call these variables to see what they have. Javascript 101. When  you deployed through Mist, it did compile and deploy in 1 step.

Comment: Ok I think i am on the right track now. Thanks for your help!