# How to generate an ethereum address?

Tags: addresses

How an EOA, contract address can be achieved?

What is an mechanism for generating these?

Comment: For EOA see this question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated

Comment: For contract addresses see this question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed

Answer (score 1):

The `sender` and `nonce` are RLP encoded and then hashed with `Keccak-256`.
You can use [ethereumjs-utils](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util) to generate EOA addresses.

```
contractAddress = ethUtil.bufferToHex(ethUtil.generateAddress(address, nonce));
```

address = Senders Address

nonce = Senders Transaction count

Comment: You can use the `contract:address` method in `eth-cli` to do this: https://github.com/protofire/eth-cli#contractaddress (Disclaimer: I'm one of the contributors)

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy a contract from an EOA and don't specify otherwise, the respective EOA will be the owner.

You can use nodejs & web3 to deploy the contract: [Deploy contract from NodeJS using web3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7255/deploy-contract-from-nodejs-using-web3)

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript,

EOA(wallet address): '0x' + keccak256(publicKey).slice(-40)

Like above, wallet address can be achieved by public key. 1) hash it with keccak256. 2) slice rightmost 20 bytes(40 words). 3) Add a '0x' prefix

Contract address: '0x' + keccak256(rlp.encode([sender, nonce])).toString('hex').slice(-40)

Like above, contract address can be achieved by sender's nonce and sender's address. 1) encode sender's address and sender's nonce with rlp. 2) hash it with keccak256. 3) slice right most 20 bytes(40 words). 4) Add a '0x prefix.

You can check generating contract address by yourself, googling blockchains.tools which may help your understanding.